# Gráfico usando geom_line y combinando color y linetype genera líneas en zigzag

Tags: r

Tengo un conjunto de datos relativamente grande que puedo compartir [aquí](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ga42rg8ch3hd9fy/datos.csv?dl=0).

Intento realizar un gráfico en el que se pinten todas las líneas correspondientes a los valores de y en x = G, con los datos agrupados por I y P; de tal manera que los niveles de la variable I aparezcan con un color diferente y los niveles de la variable P aparezcan con un tipo de línea diferente.

El problema que tengo es que el gráfico que obtengo es un gráfico de líneas en zig-zag a lo largo del eje x. Lo que se busca, obviamente, es que se pinte una línea para cada combinación de datos, evitando el zig zag. He leído que este problema podría estar relacionado con la forma en que se agrupan los datos. He intentado varias combianciones de agrupaciones de datos usando `group` pero no consiguo resolver el problema.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
#Seleccionamos colores
colores<-brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")[c(9,11,1)]    

#Graficamos
data %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = G, y = y, color = I, linetype=P)) +
      geom_line(aes(linetype=P,color=I),size=0.2)+
      scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed")) +
      scale_color_manual(values=colores) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by=25), limits=c(0,100)) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1, by=0.25), limits=c(0,1)) +
      labs(x = "Tiempo", y = "Valor") +
      theme_classic()
```

También he probado a añador `group=interaction(I, P)` dentro de `ggplot(aes())`, con el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabajando en el problema que tienes , encontré esta forma de generarlo espero que sea lo que deseas

```
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/rall8/Desktop/Stack/datos_1.csv")

library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)
#Seleccionamos colores
colores<-brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")[c(9,11,1)]    

#Graficamos
data %>%
ggplot(aes(x = G, y = y,color = I, group=interaction(P,I),linetype=P)) +
geom_line(size=0.2)+
labs(x = "Tiempo", y = "Valor") +
theme_classic()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La variable P define el tipo de línea mientras las variables "P" e "I" define el color de las líneas

Comment: mucha sgracias por la ayuda. Encontré una solución en el foro en inglés:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66402573/how-to-avoid-zig-zag-plot-when-using-geom-line-with-color-and-linetype?noredirect=1#comment117393132_66402573 El problema es que faltaba una variable para identificar I,P. Otro problema es que los datos de la variable y se repiten mucho, por lo que el gráfico resultante es bastante abigarrado. Gracias,